# Adding values from two source into List<T>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<dynamic> filledTable = new List<dynamic>();` which I then add a list of strings to as

```
foreach (var items in dt.AsEnumerable())
{
   var serialList = serialDto.ValidateSerialNumberList(items.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER"), customerId);
   filledTable.Add(serialList);
}
```

`ValidateSerialNumberList()` method return me a `List<dynamic>`containing items based on what is returned from the `Sproc`.

Now I would like to amend my `filledTable` list by adding data from my `DataTable dt` which is passed in.

If I do

```
filledTable.AddRange(new object[] { serialList, items });
```

Then the list is returned with two items first being the `serialList` and second being `items` however, I'm trying to add them as one item. Can someone tell me how to achieve this please.

Update:

For example if my `ValidateSerialNumberList()` method returns me

1. SERIALNUMBER = 123456
2. PRODUCTTYPE = SOMEPRODUCT
3. SHIPPED = YES
4. VALID = TRUE

And My `DataTable dt` has the columns

1. SERIALNUMBER = 123456
2. FAULT = SOME FAULT DESCRIPTION
3. OTHER INFO = SOME OTHER INFO

I want to populate a list as one with the above items where serial number matches

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve, but wouldn't a simple `filledTable.Add(new object[] { serialList, items });` do the thing (i.e. "add them as one item")?

Comment: Why do you use `AddRange`?

Comment: Make a list of object, AddRange(serialList), AddRange(items) and this new list to filledTable.

Comment: @DirkVollmar I've updated my question, please let me know if any more info is required

Comment: According to your update, do you want to merge those lists?

Comment: @rbr94 yes, so I get it back as one item in the list rather than two separate ones

Comment: @tolanj can you provide an example please